Pinyin tone marks
Often when people want to type some pinyin, they put tone marks as numbers:

ni3 chi1le ma?

But it's much easier to read with tone marks as accents:

wǒ chīguòle

I wrote a pinyin formatter (available at shinyandnew.ca) which allows for easy formatting of pinyin based on numeric tone entry (type v for ü). Maybe this, or something like it, could be integrated here?

+1 I approve this suggestion.

There is the char ŏ (014F) in Unicode.

Nice. On MS Windows, you can also use Pinyinput, which allows you to input pinyin wherever you are typing, instead of copying it from a web form.

If you are proposing to integrate some pinyin input method, I agree then. :)

If by "pinyin input method" you mean "type in some pinyin and hanzi appears" then no, that's not what I am suggesting. I mean you type in pinyin words with tone numbers and they auto-convert to pinyin words with tone accents.

@Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Oh, now I realize it's ambiguous... I meant what you meant, type "zhong1" and you get "zhōng".
